# Complex inner product identity

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-spaces, inner-products

[Complex inner product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianInnerProduct.html)

In $\mathbb{C}^d, $$v\not = 0$ and $w=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

Let $\langle v, w \rangle = \rho e^{i\theta}$ with $\rho >0$. If $\tilde{v} = e^{-i\theta}v$, then $\langle \tilde{v}, \tilde{v} \rangle = \langle v, v \rangle$.

I tried that $$\langle \tilde{v}, \tilde{v} \rangle = \langle e^{-i \theta}v, e^{-i \theta}v \rangle = e^{-2i \theta} \rho e^{i \theta} = \rho e^{-i \theta}.$$

Is the second equality correct? How can we prove the identity $\langle \tilde{v}, \tilde{v} \rangle = \langle v, v \rangle$? Is it true that for any $v$ and $w$ in $\mathbb{C}^d$, $\langle v, w \rangle = \rho e^{i\theta}$? What decides the value of $\theta$?

Comment: What is $w$? ${}{}$

Comment: @user251257 I edited it. $w=\lambda v$.

Comment: Look at how the inner product is defined. It is a function if you wish, that takes two vectors and gives a scalar (complex in your case, it seems). Can you express any complex number in tbe form you give? Can you write/split $\exp{i\theta}$ (may not be necessary) somehow and/or use properties/axioms of an inner product? (for example, how do you 'take out' a scalar, from inside the inner product bracket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\langle \tilde{v}, \tilde{v} \rangle = \langle e^{-i \theta}v, e^{-i \theta}v \rangle= e^{-i \theta} \overline{e^{-i \theta}}\langle v,v \rangle=e^{-i \theta} e^{i \theta}\langle v,v \rangle=\langle v,v \rangle$.